# Range validation attribute not validating

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I have an object, lets say this:

```
public class Person{
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see the `Id` should atleast contain 1 and the name field is required.

I have this validation method:

```
private static void ValidateObject(Person obj){
    var context = new ValidationContext(obj, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, results);

    if (!isValid)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(results.First().ErrorMessage);
    }        
}
```

If I leave the `Name` empty, it will throw an error. Correct!
If I leave the `Id` to 0, it will NOT throw an error. And this is what I can't figure out. The variable `isValid` is also true (should be false)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What application type are you using? MVC, WPF?

Comment: It's just an object and a method in a class calling the validation. Nothing fancy. No MVC, WPF, ASP or whatever, just a class library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to adjust the call to [Validator.TryValidateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772.aspx) with an extra parameter called 'validateAllProperties' and set it to true. If you omit it or set it to false (default) not-required properties will not be validated.

```
private static void ValidateObject(Person obj){
    var context = new ValidationContext(obj, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, context, results, true);

    if (!isValid)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(results.First().ErrorMessage);
    }        
}
```